# Access Windows share via CIFS and Kerberos: "Key has been revoked"

Tags: samba, cifs, active-directory, kerberos

I'm trying to mount a Windows share on a Linux host (Ubuntu 16.04) using Kerberos / Active Directory authentication. The Linux host has been joined to the AD, and I can access shares on it from the Windows world. Also, I can access my Windows share from Linux via username. What doesn't work however is this:

```
$ sudo mount -t cifs -o sec=krb5i //mysrv/scratch mount
mount error(524): Unknown error 524
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

$ sudo mount -t cifs -o sec=krb5i,vers=3.0 //mysrv/scratch mount
mount error(128): Key has been revoked
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

`kinit` works for my user principal

```
$ kinit first.last@COMPANY-DE.LOCAL
$ klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000
Default principal: first.last@COMPANY-DE.LOCAL

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
07.02.2019 14:28:51  08.02.2019 00:28:51  krbtgt/COMPANY-DE.LOCAL@COMPANY-DE.LOCAL
        renew until 08.02.2019 14:28:48
```

I can also do this to get a service principal for my host:

```
$ kinit -k
$ klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000
Default principal: host/buildserver-01.company-de.local@COMPANY-DE.LOCAL

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
07.02.2019 14:28:30  08.02.2019 00:28:30  krbtgt/COMPANY-DE.LOCAL@COMPANY-DE.LOCAL
        renew until 08.02.2019 14:28:30
```

My intention is that I can mount a remote share, and have different unix users access this share by each doing `kinit`. I think it should work, but is not clear to me what the prerequisites for this are. Any ideas?